# How to get html-loader to process HTML's script's src?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-html-loader

## Static HTML generation with Webpack

I've setup a static website generator using Webpack as bundler and [html-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader) in order to generate a dependency tree and process found dependencies (CSS, images, JS, etc).

To do so, I managed html-loader's options to process elements with `src` or `href` attributes.

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '[name].html',
            },
        },
        { loader: 'extract-loader' },
        {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: {
                attrs: [':src', 'link:href'],
            },
        },
    ]
}
```

### How to reproduce

Full code can be found [here](https://github.com/dreadcast/html-loader).

```
npm i
npm start
```

### What I get

HTML is properly processed, links/URL are correctly substituted expect javascript assets. Neither chunks are ouput nor script's `src` attributes are substituted.

Have I missed something in my config?

Did I bump into a html-loader or Webpack bug?

Comment: may help : https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/536. But why d'ont your require your js file in your index.js file (entry point)

Comment: My entry point(s) require HTML files (actually Nunjucks templates). Then I want each template to be able to load its own bundle...

Comment: Did you manage to do what you were trying to do?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not manage to get this working, so I stick to our in-house solution